# Not able to sucessfully install Basemap in my python 3.6 windows 10

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

i am trying to install basemap in my python 3.6 but after proceeding few steps while installing Error come. Successful install don't happen.I have update my pip , my pip is uptodate . Kindly see the details provided and let me know how to install Basemap , i want to use it as matplotlib Basemap.

```
C:\Users\incois-sms\Python\Scripts>pip install basemap-1.1.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Processing c:\users\incois-sms\python\scripts\basemap-1.1.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting pyproj>=1.9.3 (from basemap==1.1.0)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/29/72/5c1888c4948a0c7b736d10e0f0f69966e7c0874a660222ed0a2c2c6daa9f/pyproj-1.9.5.1.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
using bundled proj4..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\incois-sms\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 490, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
    return self.find_available_vc_vers()[-1]
IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\INCOIS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9cnlu9qh\pyproj\setup.py", line 72, in <module>
    objects = cc.compile(['nad2bin.c', 'src/pj_malloc.c'])
  File "c:\users\incois-sms\python\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 345, in compile
    self.initialize()
  File "c:\users\incois-sms\python\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 238, in initialize
    vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
  File "c:\users\incois-sms\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 185, in msvc14_get_vc_env
    return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_min_ver=14.0).return_env()
  File "c:\users\incois-sms\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 844, in __init__
    self.si = SystemInfo(self.ri, vc_ver)
  File "c:\users\incois-sms\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 486, in __init__
    self.vc_ver = vc_ver or self._find_latest_available_vc_ver()
  File "c:\users\incois-sms\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 493, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
    raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(err)
distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

----------------------------------------
```

Command `python setup.py egg_info` failed with error code 1 in `C:\Users\INCOIS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9cnlu9qh\pyproj\`

Comment: you want to use `conda` on windows. building packages like this from source is not worth the effort.

Comment: Install `Microsoft Visual C++ with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools" `

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can install conda and follow this below URL.

Yes there was issue before windows, now they fixed it.

https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/345